# Using pickle with cucumber and factory_girl to create associated models and pass parameters through to the nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, pickle, matcher

I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
    def before_create
        self.profile ||= Profile.new
    end
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

And I have the following factories:

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.email                 { Factory.next :email }
  user.association           :profile
end

Factory.define :profile do |profile|
  profile.name  'Name'
end
```

So this is my feature:

```
Given a profile: "John" exists with name: "John"
And a user: "John" exists with profile: profile "John"
```

Is there a way I can improve this? I would like to be able to write something like this:

```
Given a user: "John" exists with a profile: profile "John" exists with name: "John"
```

And it creates something along the lines of:

```
Factory(:user, :profile => Factory(:profile, :name) )
```

Its almost that I need a nested matcher. Can you suggest a step for this?

Or can you suggest an alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your models. `User` does not appear to have a `name` column, but you are referring to the user "John" in your feature. Does this mean you are checking the `name` column in the associated `Profile`? Maybe you could elaborate on the thinking behind this design.

Comment: The thinking behind the design was to separate a users profile and account from the user, however the enormity of the problems i have encountered when trying to write tests for such a design suggests to me that there is something wrong. I think it would make more sense to just dump everything into the users table/model and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to write your steps in a more declarative style, and avoid putting brittle incidental details into your scenarios.

Here are some references:

- http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/home/refuctoring-your-cukes
- http://aslakhellesoy.com/post/11055981222/the-training-wheels-came-off